# Updating list item in array adapter

Tags: android, arraylist

I have been trying to update the last element of my list view by doing the following

```
mNavTitles.remove(last_position); //mNavTitles is an ArrayList<string>
mNavTitles.add("Notifications Disabled");
((BaseAdapter)mDrawerList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However this doesn't work. If I choose to add or remove exclusively, this works just fine. Why can't I update my list by removing and then adding? And if this is not possible how would I go about updating this in the simplest way possible? I've seen solutions that involve recreating the whole array list but I really don't understand why that's necessary when adding and removing both work.

EDIT, more context:

This is happening inside of the onitemclick listener from my nav drawer. When the last nav item is clicked it is supposed to update the title text of the item. I am unable to update onclick, merely add xor remove a list item.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What method are you trying to update from?

Answer (score 0):

mNavTitles.set(index-number, "new value");

For example if you want to update your 5th element in your arraylist. You shoul try follow

mNavTitles.set(5, "new value");

Comment: You would think this would make sense, but it didn't work at all for me (unlike 'add' and 'remove'). Also I still need to notifydatasetchanged since I'm editing the list live.